# Accessing the virtual machine installed on ESXi server from a remote computer without the use of Vsphere client

Tags: vmware-esxi

hey folks I am new to the virtualization environment and have recently installed a esxi server on one of my CPUs and have installed the Vsphere Client program on another computer. I have also been able to install a virtual machine(win 7) on my esxi server with the help of the management s/w i.e the Vsphere client. Now i want to connect to/or access the virtual machine that i installed on ESXI server from different laptops/desktops without using the Vsphere clent. I don't want to use the conventional RDP method to access the remote Virtual Machine.

Comment: This is silly. Why wouldn't you use RDP or an equivalent solution to access the virtual machine directly?

Answer (score 8):

If you want to access the console, so that you're doing the equivalent of plugging a keyboard or mouse into the VM (Or using iLO / DRAC) then you *must* use the vSphere Client. That's just how it works on ESXi.

Other than that, you treat the VM like any other machine and connect to it however you would if it were a physical machine. With Windows you'd need to use RDP, Linux SSH etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can VNC to the console of a virtual machine without installing any VNC server software inside the guest by editing the .VMX file. This article refers to GSX server but the steps are the same for ESXi 5/4.1; I haven't tested this on 5.1.
http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1246